# Какой падеж: "в лесУ"?

Tags: склонение

Если просклонять единственное число существительного ЛЕС, то ни в одном не будет словоформы лесУ. Словарь указывает на использование т.н. *местного падежа*.

Так какой же падеж у данной словоформы?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Сейчас т. н. местный падеж (локатив) отдельно не выделяется, он объединился с предложным. Его называют вторым предложным. Второй предложный падеж характеризуется особыми окончаниями у группы существительных мужского рода в единственном числе и переносом ударения на окончание ***у*** у некоторых существительных женского рода 3-го склонения в единственном числе: в шкафу, в лесу, на берегу, в носу, на лбу, в бою; в печ**и**, в тиш**и**, в кров**и**, в тен**и**, на мел**и**, на маз**и** (ср. "первый"  предложный падеж: о шк**а**фе, о л**е**се, о кр**о**ви, о т**е**ни). Сейчас  местный падеж употребляется только в сочетании с предлогами ***в*** и ***на*** у некоторых обстоятельств времени и места:
***Оно висит на двери́ / Он настаивает на две́ри.***
Степень обязательности употребления формы местного падежа в разных случаях разная. Для некоторых существительных мужского рода употребление окончания **-у** в предложном падеже после предлогов ***в*** и ***на*** в составе предложной группы с пространственным значением является обязательным (в боку, во рту, в плену, в раю, на лбу, на полу, на виду, ср. также фразеологизмы *пойти на поводу у кого*; *раз в году*), для некоторых - вариативным (в стогу - в стоге, в хлеву - в хлеве, на балу - на бале), для некоторых  -  невозможным (док -  в доке, не в доку; двор - во дворе, не во двору; зал - в зале, не в залу).

Подробнее об этом и других вариациях в падежах - здесь: [Падежи](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6#1)