# В 2015 году: какой падеж?

Tags: падежи

Во фрагменте предложения

> Самым обсуждаемым в 2015 год**у** является вопрос о...

в каком падеже употреблено слово *год*? Ни под один из стандартных шести это употребление не подходит. По аналогии с:

```
о лЕсе -> в лесУ
об аэропОрте -> в аэропортУ
```

можно отнести эту форму слова к *местному падежу (предложный II)*, но насколько это верно по смыслу?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Форма "в году" относится к местному падежу, обозначающему место и время совершения действия. 
[Падеж](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/48546/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b6-%d0%b2-%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%a3)

В своей статье ''К СЕМАНТИКЕ РУССКОГО ЛОКАТИВА ("ВТОРОГО ПРЕДЛОЖНОГО" ПАДЕЖА) '' В. А. Плунгян пишет '' Особой проблемой является падежное оформление конструкций с предлогами в и на с временным значением: для некоторых семантических групп контекстов возможен только винительный падеж (ср. одолжить на минуту, приехать на неделю), но для большинства контекстов правила выбора между предложным и винительным являются весьма нетривиальными (ср. в тот год и в том году; в эту минуту, но в этом месяце, и т.п.). – Серж 2 дня назад

Подробный анализ проблемы (с обсуждением возможных семантических правил распределения) см. в работе Nesset, in prep. Для нас, однако, существенно прежде всего то, что те временные контексты, которые требуют предложного падежа, по своим морфологическим свойствам аналогичны пространственным, поэтому ниже контексты типа в этом месяце / в шестом часу будут по умолчанию включаться в число пространственных. – Серж 2 дня назад

Таким образом, применительно к конструкциям с предлогами в / на и формами предложного падежа можно говорить о двух крупных семантических классах контекстов: пространственных (в широком смысле, т.е. включая и временные употребления) и непространственных.'

Comment: Просто название *местный* интуитивно не относит его к использованию в обстоятельствах времени)

Comment: Спасибо огромное за столь подробный комментарий. Очень приятно читать ваши продуманные объяснения, всегда отсылающие к интересным статьям и работам.

Comment: @Серж думаю, что этот комментарий стоит включить в текст ответа.

Comment: *Просто название местный интуитивно...*  - это не так. Фактически местный падеж сочетает в себе рудименты нескольких древних падежей (падежных форм), связанных с локализацией, вреvеннОй или пространственной, что хорошо видно, например, для местного падежа женского рода на Ь (третьего склонения): "Говорил о шЕрсти, кОови", но "весь в шерстИ", "храм Спаса на кровИ"  и т.д. Это третья функция местного падежа. Есть и ещё. Филологи иногда придумывают им специальные обозначения, чтобы не путать, это не столь существенно.  Главное: не замыкаться на исключительно пространственной  функции.